# Text besides Image doesnt work for specific image. Why?

Tags: html, css, image, positioning

i use the following code to put text beside image:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:bottom">
        <p><img src="CIMA/CimaMetanoia.png" alt="Cool"   height="50%" width="50%" /></p>
    </div>

    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <p class="text"> 
        <div> <font color="#d54646"><b>MOVIDA</b> es un ministerio christiano, latino, internacional <br> e interdenominacional con el propósito de: </font> <br><br> </div>
        <div> <b><font color="#2089a4">DESAFIAR</font></b> <br>al joven christiano a una entrega total a Dios y a crecer en su relación con El.<br><br> </div>
        <div> <b><font color="#2089a4">PROVEERLE</font></b> <br> herramientas para que descubra sus dones y talentos.<br><br> </div>
        <div> <b><font color="#2089a4">MOTIVARLO</font></b> <br> a un servicio comprometido en su iglesia local y movilizarlo a las misiones mundiales.<br> </div>
        </p>
    </div>
```

However, even if i change the size of my image, it is always above the text... why?

---

Finally i used the template "initializr" (see google), because it makes all responsive too, which i needed! thank you all anyway!

Answer (score 0):

A commenter asked that I work with `your code only`. So, here's a solution using your code, to make the 2 divs sit next to each other.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 49%;">
<p><img alt="Cool" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" height="50%" width="50%" /></p>
</div>

<div style="float: right; width: 49%;">
<p class="text"> 
<div> <font color="#d54646"><b>MOVIDA</b> es un ministerio christiano, latino, internacional <br> e interdenominacional con el propósito de: </font> <br><br> </div>
<div> <b><font color="#2089a4">DESAFIAR</font></b> <br>al joven christiano a una entrega total a Dios y a crecer en su relación con El.<br><br> </div>
<div> <b><font color="#2089a4">PROVEERLE</font></b> <br> herramientas para que descubra sus dones y talentos.<br><br> </div>
<div> <b><font color="#2089a4">MOTIVARLO</font></b> <br> a un servicio comprometido en su iglesia local y movilizarlo a las misiones mundiales.<br> </div>
</p>
</div>
```

*EDITED*
Below I've posted code that in my mind is better formatted for your solution. Just wanted to offer up some alternatives.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .left {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
    }
    .left img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .right {
      float: right;
    }
    .movida strong {
      color: #d54646;
    }
    .common strong {
      color: #2089a4;
    }
    .text strong {
      display: block;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<div class="left">
    <p><img src="CIMA/CimaMetanoia.png" alt="Cool" /></p>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <p class="text"> 
        <div><span class="movida"><strong>MOVIDA</strong>es un ministerio christiano, latino, internacional e interdenominacional con el propósito de:</span></div>
        <div><span class="common"><strong>DESAFIAR</strong>al joven christiano a una entrega total a Dios y a crecer en su relación con El.</span></div>
        <div><span class="common"><strong>PROVEERLE</strong>herramientas para que descubra sus dones y talentos.</span></div>
        <div><span class="common"><strong>MOTIVARLO</strong>a un servicio comprometido en su iglesia local y movilizarlo a las misiones mundiales.</span></div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: hmm unfortunately this doesnt work on my screen. the image and the text are not on one level. the text on the right also leaves the screen...

Comment: You can specify a `width` on your `.right` div. Not sure why the downvote? I cleaned up a lot of elements which shouldn't have been used, and offered up a cleaner, more succinct way to solve your problem. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Using `<br>` for spacing, `<font>` for styling, and `inline styles` isn't really the correct way to write the aforementioned code.

Answer (score 0):

you might try adding the position property to the image

so, in this case,

```
image{position:fixed , absolute , relative; top:50%; left:50%;}
```

or this may work as well:

```
<div>
<image></image>
<p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The text is pushed below the image because the combined width of the two container divs is wider than the page, so it pushes the second div below the first one:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:bottom;width:200px;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Luby/